How to access a non-default database in firebase project using Python?
I'm using python to interact with a firestore database. Up until now I've been using the following code to interact with the (default) database. Now that I've added a non-default database (through the web interface), that I'd like to use for staging, I don't know how to interact with it (i.e. add data, delete documents, etc.). To be clear, this is within the same project / app in Firebase.
I've read through the documentation and other threads, but have found nothing that works. Is there a databaseURL that I can pass through? If so, what would that be?
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

firebase_cred_path = "./service-account-private-key.json"

cred = credentials.Certificate(firebase_cred_path)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

data = {"testkey": "testvalue"}

db.collection("firestore-collection-name").add(data)



Pass the name to initialize_app, e.g. name="staging",? From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77073331/accessing-firebase-named-database-from-python-sdk. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77571877/how-can-i-open-a-specific-database-on-google-firestore-in-python

if that doesn't work, it might not (yet) be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78533417/how-to-write-to-a-firestore-db-other-than-default-in-a-python-cloud-function
